# Why is there old PHP with LiteSpeed Web Server?

Tags: php, web-server, litespeed

I have Litespeed Web Server Enterprise v4.0.1 installed and configured.
I decided to check phpinfo() and it turned out that I have php 4.4.9

I checked in LWS Admin panel and there are three script handlers. One php5 another php 4 and just php.
Regular php is set to php5. But howcome it still uses php4?

Will server switch to php5 automatically when needed?

Answer (score 0):

By default Litespeed comes with PHP 4 compiled, but you can easily compile (nearly) the latest PHP 5 version from the admin console (Actions -> Compile PHP). I.e. the current Litespeed version is 4.1.10 and the latest PHP version available for building within the Litespeed admin console is 5.3.8.